# Jmeter listener showing " javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?"

Tags: java, jmeter

Using jmeter I am trying to run a test that was recorded using HTTP proxy Server. But on playing the test following exception is thrown in the listener.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:521)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:355)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:722)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1029)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1056)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1040)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:405)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.sample(HTTPSampler.java:483)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:951)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:348)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

The website also had certificate issue for which i permanently stored exception.What can be the reasons for this error?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are trying to establish an SSL/TLS connection using a port on the server that speaks HTTP and not HTTP**S**. Make sure you have the correct port - usually 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: which port do you want me to set proxyserver port or request default port?

Comment: I assumed that the proxy was only for recording the session. If you replay the recorded session directly connect to the right port on the server.